# I Don't Want to Let Google+ upload the images folder of my application

Tags: android, google-plus

I looked online to see if this was possible:

I don't want my application to upload images on `Google+` when the user has not checked the option `Instant Upload`.

My application downloads images from the web, and saves the images in a SD folder at the root of the SD where icons and similar images are stored. I don't want these images uploaded into instant upload `Google+` folder. I had thought delete the images that my application download, but, I don't wanna access with Google user. In brief, I don't want to let to `Google+` upload the images folder of my application.

Comment: i'm not sure if it works on all devices but you could store your images in folder which name starts with dot(aka private folders)

Answer (score 2):

Add another file in the folder with name `.nomedia`. 
Hopefully Google+ wont touch them after you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. All of you are great. I proved both solutions, but the solution with a dot I can't use because my application will be installed in multiple devices and should be as standar as possible. In my code I use the solution with a nomedia file. I created automatically with a small code. I write it below if somebody is lost in this amazing world.

```
File noMedia = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + context.getPackageName() + "/.nomedia");
noMedia.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(noMedia);
OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
myOutWriter.close();
fOut.close();
```

Thanks again.